Windows 11: DISM Error 0x800f081f - Source Files Could Not Be Found During Offline Repair
I'm facing an issue on a Windows 11 machine that cannot connect to the internet due to cybersecurity restrictions. Here's what I've tried so far:
SFC Command:
I ran the sfc /scannow command, and the result was:

"Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix
some of them." The log file details are available at:
C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.

DISM Command:
Following that, I tried to restore the system image using the DISM command:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
However, I received the following error:

Error: 0x800f081f - The source files could not be found.

To repair the image, I downloaded a Windows 11 ISO, mounted it, (Index 6, Windows 11 Pro) from my local machine for an offline repair. Since the machine is not connected to the internet, I used the following DISM command with the /limitaccess option:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:E:\Sources\install.wim:6 /limitaccess
But I still encountered the same error: The source file could not be found.
I then copied the install.wim file to a folder on my local D: drive, gave full write permissions to the folder(Created Windows 11 Folder), and ran the following command:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:D:\Windows11\Sources\install.wim:6 /limitaccess
However, I continue to receive the error:

Error: 0x800f081f - The source files could not be found.

Tried Using install.esd:
I also tried using the new windows 11 image with install.esd file from the Windows 11 ISO instead of install.wim, but I still encountered the same error.
I also tried the dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup command, and dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /resetbase command  but the issue persists.
I used the same procedure on a Windows 10 machine, and it worked perfectly. This problem only occurs on the Windows 11 machine.
Details:
Environment: No internet access.
Error: 0x800f081f - The source files could not be found.
Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve this issue for Windows 11, especially in an offline environment?
Any help would be appreciated!

You shouldn't need to set a source. By default, WinSxS should be used. What files were detected as being corrupt?  You might be better off just doing an in-place install.  Furthermore, unless you are the system administrator, you shouldn't be trying to solve this problem yourself. Having elevated permissions is the same as being authorized to fix a problem like this. You used the 6 index of the windows image. What version of Windows is the 6th index? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment. You need to mount the ISO by the way.

The system is Windows 11 Pro, and I have already mounted the Windows 11 ISO. Based on the mounted image, Index 6 corresponds to Windows 11 Pro. I have no issue making changes to the PC's settings if needed.

Can you provide the list of editions within the image you are using?

Since you have the ISO, why not perform repair, keeping files, rather than use DISM to make repairs? The repair process goes fairly rapidly, compared with full install.

This is such a great question!! If only the answers were available!
